# Prove: if $f$ continuous and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=0$ so $f(x)=0$

Tags: integration, proof-verification

> Let $f:[a,b]\Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $f$ is continuous and nonnegative such that  $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=0$. Prove that $f(x)=0$ on $[a,b]$

1. It is given that $f(x)$ is integrable (either because of the fact that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=0$ or because it is continuous in a closed interval and therefore continuous and bounded in a closed interval). Therefore, $0=\lim_{\lambda(x)\rightarrow0}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(c_i)\Delta x_{i}=(b-a)\cdot \lim_{\lambda(x)\rightarrow0}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(c_i)$ because $(b-a)$ is positive $\lim_{\lambda(x)\rightarrow0}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(c_i)=0$ and because $f$ is continuous and nonnegative $f(c)=0$ and therefore $f(x)=0$
2. let us assume that $f(x)\neq0$ because $f$ is continuous and nonnegative $f(x)>0$; now $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ (either because of the fact that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=0$ or because it is continuous in a closed interval and therefore continuous and bounded in a closed interval). 
   So
   $$0=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\leq \mid\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\mid\leq \int_{a}^{b}\mid f(x)\mid=0$$

Therefore $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

Are the proofs valid?

Comment: @smcc quoted answer is the standard one, which I rather like. Yours I really don't understand: in the first part, you are trying to argue via Riemann sums, but the argument is flawed. In the second part the sequence of inequalities is trivial as the function is positive, and you actually started with a proof by contradiction, but then didn't look for a contradiction..

Comment: $\frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h} f(x) dx = f(a) + \frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h} (f(x)-f(a)) dx$. If $f$ is continuous then $\sup_{ x \in [0,h]} |f(x)-f(a)| \to 0$ as $h \to 0$,  So  $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_a^{a+h} f(x) dx = f(a)$

Comment: @b00nheT Thank for the feedback, in 1 can I fix it to show that $\forall c_{i}\in[a,b],f(c_{i})=0$?

As for 2, can I use darboux sum? $m(b-a)=M(b-a)$ and we know that $m=M$ so $m=M=0$ in contradiction of $f(x)>0$?

Answer (score 1):

The point is, if a **continuous** function is positive at one single point, $f(x_0)=\epsilon$, then it must be $f(x)\geq \epsilon/2$ in an interval containing $x_0$. (This follows from an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument applied to definition of continuity.)

Now, that $f\geq \epsilon/2$ over an interval of nonzero length, this contributes to the integral a strictly positive quantity. Since $f$ is nonnegative, this won't be cancelled in other parts, thus, the whole integral will be strictly positive.